# Missing OnClientClick (or onclick in HTML) for asp:Button if I use Enabled=false

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

In my page, I have a group of two radio buttons. If click on radio button 2, it will activate a search button. If user click on this search button, it will use jQuery .ajax call to retrieve data and display in a jqGrid.

The search button has to be disabled at start up. By disabled, I mean if user clicks on it, nothing should happen.

As the button is asp button, I use Enabled as:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnClientClick="return SearchAccessCode()" />
```

Here is the code for detecting/handling radio button group toggling:

```
$('input[name$=radioGroup]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[name$=radioGroup]:checked').val() == "rbFirst") {
        $('#<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

When I debug my page, after clicking on the second radio button (rbSecond), the Search button is enabled. I click on it and nothing happens! I check the HTML generated and find out it is different from other button. There is no onclick() associated with it!

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch" value="Search" id="MainContent_btnSearch" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" />
```

From the web, I know that the `Enabled` will be transated to `disabled` in HTML. So I replace the `Enabled` with `disabled`.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Disabled="True" OnClientClick="return SearchAccessCode()" />
```

Open up the HTML generated and find out it is same as other asp button. Meaning: it has onclick(). Of course, when I press the Search button, the search function is actually performed!

```
 <input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return SearchAccessCode();__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="MainContent_btnSearch" Disabled="True" />
```

I just could not help but to ask **why**. As Javascript can be inserted into an ASP.NET page, if a button is disabled using `Enabled="false"` (the Microsoft way), I can enable it back using JavaScript. But at this time, I will lose the connection between the button and the function pointed to by onclick()!

Comment: Why would it have the function? It is disabled anyway - enabling it will return the function

Comment: After enable the button, the button will *not* do anything. (I have edited my question to give more information.)

Comment: In my example the button triggers the onclick event as expected. Initially as well as after multiple partial postbacks. Check your browsers dev console for javascript errors. Also: If you use the html attribute `disabled`, enabling it on the server won't work.

Comment: Also: you could just post a minimal verifyable exmaple, so we can see why it fails, thus giving you a more specific answer

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour, since the button is disabled anyway and has no function. Re-enabling it, will trigger a PostBack and add the `OnClientClick` to the button:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnClientClick="console.log('btnSearch onClientClickEvent');" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Toggle Search Button" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => btnSearch.Enabled = !btnSearch.Enabled;
```

If you want to keep the OnClientClick event as markup even when the button is disabled you have to use javascript, so the PostBack is not triggered:

```
document.getElementById("<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
```

Or as you stated, just use the `disabled` attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" disabled OnClientClick="console.log('btnSearch onClientClickEvent');" />
```

Comment: I just don't like that is the default behaviour (using `Enabled="false"`). What if I use JavaScript to enable it? I have no way to access the `OnClientClick` function. I actually remove the `Enabled` from the button. I have the following JavaScript: `$(document).ready(function () { $('#<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>').prop('disbled', true);`. This way I can preserve the OnClientClick() **and** have the button disabled at startup.

Comment: That is fine, but why is this a comment to my answer and not in your question. We cannot solve your specific problem, if you do not show us your code. Your question was about why it behaves like it behaves - now it is about a specific problem. Make up your mind, what question you want to ask. Do not expect us to solve a spcific problem, if you ask a generic question without specific description and a verifiable example.